# Cursor movetofirst() & null pointer exception

Tags: android, android-cursor

I am using a `Cursor` to fetch some data stored in my `SQLite` database. The code works fine when my `Cursor` has some data from the database. But when the `Cursor` does not contain any data, I get a `NullPointerException` at `cursor.movetofirst()` method. I have used a similar code elsewhere but `movetofirst()` method does not give a `NullPointerException` elsewhere. I am trying this since a couple of days and I'm not able to figure out what is the problem. Kindly help.

```
    public class Country extends Activity {

        private DbAdapter mDb;
        private Cursor mCurSugCnt;
        String country=null;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.country);

            mDb=new DbAdapter(this);
            mDb.open();

            country= this.getIntent().getExtras().getString("country");
            fillSugCntData(country);

        }

    private void fillSugCntData(String cnt) {
        //I have tried multiple methods. The problem occurs when there is no data returned by any of the methods called
        //mCurSugCnt=mDb.fetchCatNotes("abc");
        mCurSugCnt=mDb.fetchCntNotes(cnt);

        //This is where I called the null pointer exception in case no data is returned by the cursor
        mCurSugCnt.moveToFirst();

    }


---------------------

public Cursor fetchCntNotes(String cnt){

        int id;
        Cursor appfinlist=null;
        Cursor temp=mDb.query(CNT_TABLE, new String[]{KEY_ROWID}, KEY_CNTNM + "=\"" + cnt + "\"", null, null , null, null);
        Cursor applist;

        if(temp.moveToFirst()){
            id=temp.getInt(temp.getColumnIndexOrThrow(DbAdapter.KEY_ROWID));

            applist=mDb.rawQuery("SELECT appcntid FROM appcntlist WHERE cntappid = "+id, null);
            if(applist.moveToFirst()){
                String[] cntin=new String[applist.getCount()];
                for(int i=0;i<applist.getCount();i++){
                    cntin[i]=""+applist.getInt(applist.getColumnIndexOrThrow(DbAdapter.KEY_APPCNTID));
                    Log.d("amit","countryname id cnt var: " + cntin[i]);
                    applist.moveToNext();   
                }

                String query = "SELECT * FROM applist"
                    + " WHERE _id IN (" + makePlaceholders(applist.getCount()) + ")";

                appfinlist = mDb.rawQuery(query, cntin);
                Log.d("amit","countryname id get count: " + appfinlist.getCount());
            }
        }    
            return appfinlist;
    }

    private String makePlaceholders(int count) {
        String toRet="?";

        for (int i=1;i<count;i++){
            toRet=toRet + ",?";
        }
        return toRet;
    }
```

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: I am not sure why am I getting a null pointer exception. I want to avoid getting that exception.

Comment: check what `fetchCntNotes()` returns when your query not finds any row?, seems that you are returning `null` if query fire error or no data to show.

Answer (score 6):

Always check [getCount](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html#getCount%28%29) before use it.

```
if(mCurSugCnt!=null && mCurSugCnt.getCount()>0 )
{
 mCurSugCnt.moveToFirst();
}
```

Comment: What about 'null' checking? :D

Comment: @PareshMayani I agree with you,but if query is perfect then cursor never return null

Comment: @CapDroid this is not true, i mean what if Table is not having data?

Comment: @PareshMayani I am sure, if there are not data then cursor dont have any row but it is not null

Comment: I tried this but am getting a null pointer exception in the if clause itself now..

Answer (score 1):

If you are getting `NullPointerException` on `mCurSugCnt.moveToFirst();` then you should put some kind of condition to check whether `Cursor mCurSugCnt` is **Null** or not before accessing it.

like:

```
private void fillSugCntData(String cnt) {
         mCurSugCnt = mDb.fetchCntNotes(cnt);
         if(mCurSugCnt != null && mCurSugCnt.getCount() > 0)
         {
            mCurSugCnt.moveToFirst();
         }
    }
```

Comment: FYI Method doesn't return anything

Comment: @hotveryspicy where i said `fillSugCntData()` is returning? I can see that `void` :D and I have mentioned about `fetchCntNotes()`.

Comment: `If you are getting NullPointerException from method` must be `If you are getting NullPointerException by using method` *from* itselfs says *returns*.

Comment: @hotveryspicy - Again it doesn't specified **which method**. :-)

Comment: @user370305 Method(*void*) is Method only, one cant get anything from it rather its merely a operation.

Comment: I think OP clearly mentioned it in comment of method .. `The method returns null if no data is found` . :-)

Comment: @user370305 Agree, but I'm in concern with this `If you are getting NullPointerException from method` least concern whatever OP written, I think you saying OP is correct by writting so, is it?

Comment: I tried this as well but am getting a null pointer exception in the if clause itself now..

Comment: @PareshMayani.. Thanks. I have edited my question and added the code for it

Answer (score 0):

check your code

```
Cursor appfinlist=null; 
Cursor temp=mDb.query(CNT_TABLE, new String[]{KEY_ROWID}, KEY_CNTNM + "=\"" + cnt + "\"", null, null , null, null);
```

and if there is no record find, after your block of

```
if(temp.moveToFirst()){
    ....
}
```

you return null "appfinlist" to mCurSugCnt

```
return appfinlist;
```

that is why you got Nullpointer exception, normally it won't return null object if you call query method to get cursor